# Django primary key id mapping

Tags: django, django-models

I've a model like given below/

```
class UserWidgetMapping(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser)
    widget_string = models.CharField(max_length=600L)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user_widget_mapping'
```

When I perform a query `user_widgets = UserWidgetMapping.objects.filter(user_id = user_id)` it throws an error saying `(1054, "Unknown column 'user_widget_mapping.id' in 'field list'")`. i know Django automatically assigns an id to a model automatically, but I dont want an id inside this model. For that I need to provide an attribute `primarykey = True` . But since, foreign key becomes the primary key of its own tablt, how can I perform this query?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you want an ID? It makes no sense for the ForeignKey to be the primary key, because that's not unique: the point of a foreignkey is that it's a many-to-one relationship, so many UserWidgetMappings could point to the same AuthUser, and so have the same value for `user_id`. If you don't want that, you should perhaps be using a OneToOneField instead.

I don't understand the rest of your question about the query, though: I can't see why anything would change if you gave the `primary_key=True` attribute to `user`.

Comment: I'm not able to run that query. How will I be able to run it? Any corrections?

Comment: You're going wrong my not explaining what you've done, or what's happening.